# CSS in angular project don't apply unless placed in /src directory

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ag-grid

### Problem:

---

I have an angular app with a lot of components and sub components. These were generated by running `ng generate component <component-name>` so each one has the same style of component tag:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-<component-name>',
    templateUrl: './<component-name>.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./<component-name>.component.css']
})
```

My understanding is that all CSS related to this component should be placed in `src/<component-name>/<component-name>.component.css` and should be automatically applied to the component when it is rendered.

This does not seem to be the case however, as when I put certain instructions in that CSS file they are seemingly ignored. The ones that are the most notable offenders so far are things like `text-align` and any kind of `color` tag, while tags like `font-family` or `vw`/`vh` work just fine.

On the other hand, when I put my CSS in a file like `src/styles.css` and place an import in `index.html` for this file, any CSS I have there applies correctly but applies itself to ALL components. This wouldn't be a problem except some components necessarily share naming conventions, and I have no way to specify that I don't mean `[col-id="car"]` in `table2.component.ts` but rather `[col-id="car"]` in `table5.component.ts`.

#### EDIT:

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

My current grid looks like this:

[image: Grid improperly aligned]

All cells in a given column share the value of the `col-id` tag:

[image: col-id flags shared down the column]

My `slab-grid.component.css` file contains sizing instructions for the grid itself, and a font specifier:

```
.slab-grid {
    width: 45vw;
    height: 80vh;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

I know these apply properly because if I remove the size definition, the grid becomes 1px by 1px, and if I remove the `font-family`, the whole grid turns back to the normal font as seen below. Column "Thk" does not change back because another grid in another part of the app has the same `col-id` and the overarching `styles.css` file contains a definition for `[col-id="thk"]`:

[image: Grid with font applied partially due to overlapping CSS]

So in my understanding if I were to add the following statement to `slab-grid.component.css`

```css
[col-id="yard_seq"] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

I expect I would see column `Yard Seq` which has `col-id="yard_seq"` become right aligned. In reality when I add this statement to `slab-grid.component.css`, nothing changes. If I however go to the primary css file for the project located in `src/styles.css` and add the same statement, I get the below result:

[image: Grid with correct alignment]

### Question:

---

- Why does my CSS not always apply to the relevant component if placed in `src/<component-name>/<component-name>.component.css`?

**OR**

- Is there a way to make the elements of `src/styles.css` only apply to the page when certain components are rendered?

### Solution:

---

I've found an acceptable solution to this issue. If I modify my own `/src` styles selectors from `[col-id="thk"]` to use the descendant selector `.slab-grid [col-id="thk"]`, then I can make my styles override the conflicting ones with a `!important` without editing the conflicting files.

Comment: Stuff in the global stylesheet is *supposed* to be applied globally, if you need to target it you need to do so with appropriate selectors. Could you give a [mcve] of some scoped component CSS that *isn't* being applied?

Comment: Maybe you should use :host /deep/ in certain css files when you have nested component

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you can point me to an online resource that will let me use the 'ag-grid-angular' package on something like plunkr or jsfiddle, then I absolutely can. But I don't see one of those where 'ag-grid-angular' is usable.

Comment: @WalterWhite looks like /deep/ is obsolete, and :host() doesn't do the trick

Comment: Your understanding that css should be placed in that file, and be automatically applied, is correct.  You can see an example of this (including color) in the TourOfHeroes tutorial at https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 .  So, as @johnrsharpe says, you'll need to narrow down your particular case to the Minimal Complete Verifiable example.

Comment: For the online resource that allows ag-grid-angular, I haven't tried that particular package, but try https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @LucasBurns it doesn't have to be executing, but we need to be able to *see it*, on this site. In this case it sounds like you're expecting encapsulated styles to be applied to the third party component mounted in yours, which they won't be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I’ll post an example in a bit then. I was under the impression it had to be an interactive example.

Answer (score 0):

Every component has hes on styles if you want to share the same styles between multiple components you must create a shared CSS file and then import the file on the styles.css or much better solution add the shared CSS files on the angular.json config files.

the styles from the parent component do not apply to the child components.

only and only if you add the same styles on the styles.css or include the file on the angular.json

#### example

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/scss/theme.d.scss",
              "src/scss/global-scrollbar.d.scss",
              "src/scss/acrylic.scss",
              "src/scss/buttons.scss",
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: This is the exact opposite if what I'm trying to achieve. Currently the CSS applies to more content than I want it to, I want to decrease what each piece applies to.

Comment: then you must have styles that are global. you should check what styles apply, I can't help you with that, this is simple CSS